# Equivalent of SQL 2005's SQLAgentOperatorRole (msdb ) in SQL 2000?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server

Can anyone tell me what is the Equivalent of SQL 2005's SQLAgentOperatorRole (msdb ) in SQL 2000?
I want to grant a login ability to disable a job in SQL 2000.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TargetServerRoles needs to be added to MSDB. Please refer [this](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/faq/sqlagent_scheduled_jobs_p1.aspx)

Comment: FYI: This permission give the user enough control to stop/start enable, disable, create delete any job

Answer (score 1):

First off, if you did have SQL Server 2005 then using SQLAgentOperatorRole is probably too much permission. If you only want to give the user the ability to modify a single job. In  2005 you need to make the user the owner of the job and then assign that user the SQLAgentUserRole in MSDB.

In SQL Server 2000 if you make the user the owner of the job, then no additional permissions need to be assigned.  They can then modify that job.

Comment: thanks....but i dont want to change the job owner